# alexa sdk pass session attributes

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, alexa-sdk-nodejs

[This Alexa Doc](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/request-and-response-json-reference.html#response-parameters) shows that the sessionAttributes is one of the response parameters and not within the `response` object.

I'm using the [Alexa SDK](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs) and all of the `emit` response builders only use the `response` object's parameters. For example:

```
this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, repromptSpeech, updatedIntent)
```

So how can I use `emit()` from the Alexa SDK and also pass an updated sessionAttributes in the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alexa SDK automatically serializes and includes the key-value pairs that you set on the `attributes` object before you call `emit(..)`.

More concretely, you could say:

```
this.attributes.myAttribute1 = 'some value';
this.emit(':elicitSlot', slotToElicit, speechOutput, repromptSpeech, updatedIntent);
```

And the `sessionAttributes` object will automatically be updated in the response to include:

```
'myAttribute1': 'some value`
```

For reference, you can see the implementation of *elicitSlot* in the SDK, here: https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs/blob/master/lib/response.js#L131-L143